# Min-Product Semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Is there any reason why $0$ is not part of the min-product semiring? The min-product semiring is the set $(0,\infty]$ coupled with $\min$ as the addition operation ($\infty$ is additive identity) and $.$ as the multiplication operation ($1$ is multiplicative identity).